# For the pycharm IDE how would I open a terminal in the IDE that uses an identical project environment

Tags: python, terminal, ide, pycharm

Currently when I open a terminal in or out of pycharm the path has it open up python2.7.8. My project interpreter in python points to another version installed on my system (python2.6) it all works fine except when I open a terminal from within pycharm it still points to python2.7.8. I know about .pycharmrc, but how would I have the pycharm terminal point to the project python interpreter? Is there an an easy way?