# auto activate virtualenv in PyCharm terminal window

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm with virtualenv.

Is there any method to force the activation of virtualenv, in terminal window of PyCharm, at startup of the application?

At this time, when I open PyCharm (with relative project) and the terminal window in it, I need to manual run the command (source /env/bin/activate) to enable the virtualenv on this terminal window of PyCharm.

Comment: If your default interpreter is your virtualenv interpreter, then it will be activated by default when you run a script through pycharm.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac my problem is little different. I wish to have the terminal window of PyCharm correct enabled with virtualenv. If I run some python command in terminal window of PyCharm it still refers to global python interpreter.

Comment: Well unfortunately, you're going to have this solve using bash scripts. Nothing in PyCharm to do this.

Comment: Related: [For the pycharm IDE how would I open a terminal in the IDE that uses an identical project environment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24809181/95735)

Answer (score 4):

You can find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288569/how-do-i-activate-a-virtualenv-inside-pycharms-terminal)

for Windows - Go to Settings, Terminal, Default shell and add `/K <path-to-your-activate.bat>`.

Comment: No need to even follow the link. The rest of the answer explains everything I needed to know.

Comment: This setting is global, so if you have more project with different virtualenvs, you'd set one for all.